# Redirect http www and non-SSL domains to HTTPS without multiple redirects?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, https

I'm losing link juice in multiple redirects.

I need to redirect all domain versions to my default domain i.e.

```
https://example.com
```

By all domain versions I mean `http://www`, `http://`, `https://www` and `https://`. (`index.php` for all.)

I am currently using the code below. All domains are redirecting to `https://` but not directly. If I type `http://www`, it will be redirected 3 times as in the picture. I still need to redirect `index.php`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I am using "Redirect Path" extension of Google Chrome browser to monitor the redirects.

You can see redirect 3 times:

[image: You can see redirect 3 times]

You can see redirect 2 times:

[image: You can see redirect 2 times]

Comment: The code you posted actually looks "OK" - you should only be seeing a single redirect with that code. However, you might be seeing a cached response - so ensure all intermediary caches are cleared. (I just tried your domain and it seems to redirect OK for me.) ...?

Comment: I think you've probably resolved it... Your `<VirtualHost *:443>` code snippet (in the comment, now deleted) appeared to have the wrong `ServerName` defined (`example.com` instead of `www.example.com`), which would have resulted in a redirect loop. If you are going the VirtualHost route then Tom's answer looks good as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using more VirtualHosts and redirecting instead of doing rewrites.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerName www.example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
  ...
  (put your HTTPS config & path to certs here for the redirect to work)

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerName example.com
  ...
  (This is your destination VirtualHost)

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thank you so much for out of the box answer. 

I don't have the SSH access but only WHM and Cpanel. Can i still use this code?

Comment: "...redirecting instead of doing rewrites." - Just to clarify, the OPs code is using _redirects_, it's just using mod_rewrite and not mod_alias. VirtualHost/`Redirect` is preferable, but you do need access to the server config and since the question is tagged `htaccess` I guess that's not the case.

Comment: thanks @w3dk i am in `cpanel/whm` environment. Should i just find the `conf` file and add below code or
`Cpanel` must have created these `virtualhosts` entries because HTTPS is already working on my domains/vps.