# Domain redirection with virtualhost on cpanel environment

Tags: 301-redirect, apache2, virtualhost

With reference of answer by @TomBrossman [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102119/redirect-http-www-and-non-ssl-domains-to-https-without-multiple-redirects)

I need to redirect all domain versions to my default domain i.e. `https://example.com/`. By all domain versions I mean `http://www`, `http://` and `https://www`. I don't want `htaccess redirect`.

When I add `Redirect` line in `httpd.conf`. cPanel removes it. After some research I came to know that I've 3 options to change in cPanel environment.

1. **Pre Main Include**
2. **Pre Virtual Host Include**
3. **Post Virtual Host Include**

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   **Redirect 301 / https://example.com/ (Cpanel Remove this)**
    ... 
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

Is there anyway I can redirect my domain with `VirtualHost` on cPanel? Or even by `domain registrar` or `DNS setting`?

I have a VPS with root access.

Comment: "or even domain or DNS level" - What do you mean by _domain level_? And you can't "redirect" with DNS.

Comment: I meant **domain registrar** or **DNS setting**. There might be another way i am unaware of.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about these cPanel features, but adding code to the "Post Virtual Host Include" doesn't seem like the correct way to add VirtualHosts?? But if you have "a VPS with root access", can you not edit the necessary files directly? (Btw, you can't do the required _redirection_ from your domain register or in DNS.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the options in the 'Redirects' section of cPanel?
You can add a Permanent(301) redirect for the www.
More info [can be found here...](http://www.webhostinghub.com/help/learn/cpanel/redirect-domain-www-or-non-www-url)

Comment: This will add (mod_rewrite) redirects to the `.htaccess` file, not the main server config, which would seem to be the OP's preference. (Although personally I would steer well clear of the redirects section in cPanel. Unfortunately, the code that cPanel generates is rather poor IMO and can at times break your site - particularly if you have existing directives.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer  @Julaine but w3dk is right.